# Ui bootstrap typeahead - http loaded results, multiple parameters for function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create typeahead function that can have 3 parameters binded to 3 different inputs. It would look like this:

```
   $scope.getClient = function(firstName, lastName, pesel) {
  return $http.get('http://localhost:9080/service/api/client/findAffiliated', {
    params: {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      pesel: pesel,
      sensor: false
    }
  }).then(function(response){
    return response.data.clients.map(function(item){
    return item;
    })
  });
};
```

And 3 inputs:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="loan.firstName" placeholder="name"
     uib-typeahead="client.firstName as client.firstName  for client in getClient($viewValue)"
     typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
     typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" >

     <input type="text" ng-model="loan.lastName" placeholder="lastname"
     uib-typeahead="client.lastName as client.lastName for client in getClient(null, $viewValue)"
     typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
     typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" >

     <input type="text" ng-model="loan.pesel" placeholder="pesel"
     uib-typeahead="client.pesel as client.pesel for client in getClient(null, null, $viewValue)"
     typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
     typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" >
```

But I don't know how to make it bind results to all try models.
When i'm searching by firstName i'm only getting firstName etc.
How can I make it bind to all 3 models after search?

That's how my json looks:

```
 {
"errors": [],
"clients": [
    {
        "id": 1000001,
        "firstName": "Piotr",
        "lastName": "Glut",
        "pesel": "34072916415"
    },
  {
        "id": 1000002,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "pesel": "34072916413"
    }
]
 }
```

Comment: I deleted my last comment. Use the `typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label, $event)` callback listed in the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) to update all the models after the search

Comment: Could you give my an example how to use it? I don't really understand how is works.